# Transformation of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks something like:

```
    Store   Month   Sales
0   1       Jan     1100
1   1       Feb     1300
2   1       Mar     1250
3   1       Apr     1500
4   2       Jan     900
5   2       Feb     950
6   2       Mar     800
7   2       Apr     900
```

And I would like to transform it so that it looks something like:

```
    Store   Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr
0   1       1100    1300    1250    1500
1   2       1900    1950    1800    900
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python? I have read the documentation for [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), but I still don't see how either could be used to accomplish the above transformation.

Comment: `df.pivot` is what you are looking for. `df.pivot(index='Store', columns='Month', values='Sales')`

Comment: `df.set_index(["Store", "Month"]).unstack("Month")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pivot-tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) would suffice for your use-case:

```
print(df.pivot_table(index='Store', columns=['Month'], values='Sales'))
```

```
       Apr   Feb   Jan   Mar
Store                        
1     1500  1300  1100  1250
2      900   950   900   800
```

Comment: since there is no aggregation here, then pivot is better; pivot_table can be quite slow depending on the use case

Comment: @sammywemmy Why would you assume there would be no aggregation? OP only posted a sample data-frame.

Comment: no assumption here. just taking the sample data at face value. he said he wanted an efficient transformation, hence my comment. And if we go all the way and assume that  aggregation is required, it would be more efficient to manually control it using groupby and unstack